# Cannot import _uuid_generate_random when trying to import carrot.connection

Tags: python-2.7, amqp

I have a requirement of using the carrot python library. This is the code code.

```
from carrot.connection import BrokerConnection
from carrot.messaging import Consumer
```

Both the lines are throwing an `ImportError` exception.
The exception traceback is..

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.virtualenvs/stack/lib/python2.7/site-packages/carrot/connection.py", line 14, in <module>
    from carrot.backends import get_backend_cls
  File "/.virtualenvs/stack/lib/python2.7/site packages/carrot/backends/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from carrot.utils import rpartition
  File "/.virtualenvs/stack/lib/python2.7/site-packages/carrot/utils.py", line 1, in <module>
    from uuid import UUID, uuid4, _uuid_generate_random
ImportError: cannot import name _uuid_generate_random`

Im running this on Python 2.7.13 with the latest version of `carrot` and `uuid`. I have also tried upgrading uuid.